# NullPointerException in kafka

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception, apache-kafka

I want to write data from Kafka into MySQL database. I have implemented the following code.

```
kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName));
    try {


        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> record = kafkaConsumer.poll(1000);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record1 : record) {
                if (record1.value().length() > 0) {
                    System.out.println(record1.value());
                    String value = record1.value();
                    String[] array = value.split(" ");
                    String sql = String.format("insert into data(timestamp, LogLevel,CityName,Detail) values ('%s', '%s','%s','%s')", array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]);
                    mysqlConnector.statement.executeUpdate(sql);

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hello, are you receiving data from kafka?

Comment: Can you post at which line NPE is thrown?

Comment: this line                    mysqlConnector.statement.executeUpdate(sql);

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not worth to reinvent the wheel. The best option is to used well known and tested tool: **Kafka Connect** with **[Confluent JDBC Sink Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/index.html)**

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/index.html